# How to stop scroll in progress in NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a button to automatically returns to top position into a NestedScrollView. When the scroll is not in progress, it works like a charm, otherwise if the current scrolling is in progress yet, the scroll goes to top but directly scroll a lit bit down just after...

I wrote this method:

```
private void scrollToTop() {
        mScrollView.stopNestedScroll();
        mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
```

Have you got some ideas guys to stop the current scroll and go to top immediately?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be **intercepting** user's touch when you scrolling **pragmatically**. That would require you to extend `ScrollView` overriding `scrollTo` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods and **disable** user touch while list is **scrolling**, returning touch after scroll is complete.

So the sequence would be like this:

1. Call `scrollTo` to scroll to specific position
2. Enable a flag to **disable** touch events and **begin** scrolling
3. When scroll is finished and state changed to **idle** disable flag

P.S: I can provide code example but it appears you have more expertise than me in writing codes. Cheers!

Here a code snippet:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MyScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    public static final int MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR = 1;
    boolean isAutoScrolling;

    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
        isAutoScrolling = true;
        super.scrollTo(x, y);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isAutoScrolling)
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isAutoScrolling)
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
        super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);
        if (isAutoScrolling) {
            if (Math.abs(y - oldY) < MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR  || y >= getMeasuredHeight() || y == 0
                    || Math.abs(x - oldX) < MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR || x >= getMeasuredWidth() || x == 0) {
                isAutoScrolling = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keivan! Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure about your solution. Did you test it in the same context like my problem?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with ViewPager. My scenario was animating ViewPager transition and I encountered the exact same problem.. I can provide code snippet if it helps. Though it is just overriding few method with a simple boolean flag

Comment: Yes, Keivan, with pleasure to share your code please.

Comment: Added code snippet, right now I'm searching for a way to detect when scroll is ended. though it can done via looper but i think there are better ways to do so.

Comment: @anthony hmm finally found a decent way to detect scroll ending ^^

Comment: Thank you very much Keivan!

Comment: Happy to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

A tricky solution

```
private void scrollToTop() {
    mScrollView.stopNestedScroll();
    mScrollTop = true
    mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

This method stays still, dectect scrolling and scroll is reach top(kotlin code)

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { scrollView, scorllX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
            scrollTop()
        }
    } else {
        scrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
            scrollTop()
        }
    }
    private fun scrollTop() {
        if(mScrollTop) {
            if(scrollView.scrollY == 0){
               mScrollTop = false
            } else {
               scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)
            }
        }
    }
```