# How to stop NestedScrollView scrolling when SmoothScrollTo(0, 0) called

Tags: android, xamarin, android-nestedscrollview

I want to stop NestedScrollview scrolling animation after fling and programmatically scroll to top smoothly.
In my case SmoothScrollTo(0, 0) works correct but after it previous scrolling animation continued a little.

I found very similar question:
[How to stop scroll in progress in NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994111/how-to-stop-scroll-in-progress-in-nestedscrollview)

But answer of [Keivan Esbati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6600000/keivan-esbati) doesn't work for me. Can anybody help me?

Programmatically called scroll to top:

```
    public void ScrollToTop()
        {
            if (!IsOnTopOfScroll())
            {
                ObjectAnimator.OfInt(scrollView, "scrollY", scrollView.Top).SetDuration(150).Start();
            }
        }
```

Extended NestedScrollView:

```
public class ObservableNestedScrollView : NestedScrollView, IScrollable
{
        private const int MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR = 1;
        private bool isAutoScrolling;

        public override void ScrollTo(int x, int y)
        {
            isAutoScrolling = true;
            base.ScrollTo(x, y);
        }

      public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (isAutoScrolling)
            {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            if (hasNoCallbacks())
            {
                return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            switch (ev.ActionMasked)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    mDragging = false;
                    DispatchOnUpOrCancelMotionEvent(mScrollState);
                    return false;
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    mFirstScroll = mDragging = true;
                    DispatchOnDownMotionEvent();
                    break;
            }
            return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (isAutoScrolling)
            {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            if (hasNoCallbacks())
            {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            switch (ev.ActionMasked)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    mIntercepted = false;
                    mDragging = false;
                    DispatchOnUpOrCancelMotionEvent(mScrollState);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    if (mPrevMoveEvent == null)
                    {
                        mPrevMoveEvent = ev;
                    }
                    float diffY = ev.GetY() - mPrevMoveEvent.GetY();
                    mPrevMoveEvent = MotionEvent.ObtainNoHistory(ev);
                    if (GetCurrentScrollY() - diffY <= 0)
                    {

                        if (mIntercepted)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        ViewGroup parent;
                        if (mTouchInterceptionViewGroup == null)
                        {
                            parent = (ViewGroup)Parent;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parent = mTouchInterceptionViewGroup;
                        }

                        float offsetX = 0;
                        float offsetY = 0;
                        for (View v = this; v != null && v != parent; v = (View)v.Parent)
                        {
                            offsetX += v.Left - v.ScrollX;
                            offsetY += v.Top - v.ScrollY;
                        }

                        MotionEvent mEvent = MotionEvent.ObtainNoHistory(ev);
                        mEvent.OffsetLocation(offsetX, offsetY);

                        if (parent.OnInterceptTouchEvent(mEvent))
                        {
                            mIntercepted = true;

                            mEvent.Action = MotionEventActions.Down;

                            Post(new RunnableAnonymousInnerClassHelper(parent, mEvent));
                            return false;
                        }
                        return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        protected override void OnScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY)
        {
            base.OnScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);

            if (isAutoScrolling)
            {
                if (System.Math.Abs(y - oldY) < MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR || y >= MeasuredHeight || y == 0
                        || System.Math.Abs(x - oldX) < MAX_SCROLL_FACTOR || x >= MeasuredWidth || x == 0)
                {
                    isAutoScrolling = false;
                }
            }

            if (hasNoCallbacks())
            {
                return;
            }
            mScrollY = y;

            DispatchOnScrollChanged(y, mFirstScroll, mDragging);
            if (mFirstScroll)
            {
                mFirstScroll = false;
            }

            if (mPrevScrollY < y)
            {
                mScrollState = ScrollState.UP;
            }
            else if (y < mPrevScrollY)
            {
                mScrollState = ScrollState.DOWN;
                //} else {
            }
            mPrevScrollY = y;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but I lack part of the code about `IScrollable`, `DispatchOnUpOrCancelMotionEvent` `DispatchOnDownMotionEvent` and `GetCurrentScrollY` Could you share these codes? Provide a demo that could reproduce this issue is better,

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I created demo project on GitHub
[TestNestedScrollView](https://github.com/AlexTsybin/TestNestedScrollView)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I saw your project is still utilizing Android Support packages, please upgrade them to use AndroidX for better experience. You can refer to [AndroidX migration in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration) for more information, it also includes how to migrate the packages.

I checked the other thread and tried in a clean demo, but it's not working for me either, but I do find another suggestions which works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333212/12936075

You can make your FabOnClick:

```
    private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        scrollView.Fling(0);
        scrollView.SmoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    }
```